# Computed Value not undefined

Tags: vuejs3

i want to filter out the prop in computed, the prop value is available, but computed always shows undefined. Following is my code :

```
export default {  
name: "Validation",  
props: {    
validationResult: {      
type: Object,     
required: true,   
 },  
},  
computed: {   
 filteredInvalidRules() {     
 return this.validationResult.sss.rules.filter((rule) => rule.isValid === false);  
  },  
},
```

'Validation Results' is aavailable , and has value in dev Tools.
The computed property 'filteredInvalidRules' is always undefined. How to fix it?

TIA

Comment: You know that validationResult exists, but have you checked to be sure that it has valid data in its `sss` field, and that this has valid data in its `rules` field?

Comment: data is available in all the subobjects..i added optional chaining this.validationResult?.sss?.rules. also, with same results

Comment: Hard to say without more details from your side. Are you sure that the filter is satisfied? Maybe a typo? Try to use the Vue devtools and run the filter on it directly (by using your browser's console).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's `undefined` because of the component creating steps.

I think it goes something like this (please correct me if I'm wrong):

1. the child component is created.
2. your computed property looks after `validationResult`.
3. `validationResult` is required, but has no value yet.
4. `filteredInvalidRules` returns `undefined`
5. your parent component is created and you pass the data (and you see them in your devTools).

---

#### Solution 1: add default values to your props

```js
props: {    
validationResult: {      
  type: Object,    
  default() {
    return {
      sss: {
       rules: {
         isValid: false
       }
      }
    };
  },
  required: true,
 },  
},
```

so when your child component is created, your computed property got access to the default property values.

#### Solution 2: return in computed property

```js
 filteredInvalidRules() {
     const isUndefined = obj2?.sss?.rules === undefined
     if (isUndefined) return []
         
     return this.validationResult.sss.rules.filter((rule) => rule.isValid === false);  
  },
```

this approach will return an empty array on creating the child component. I think it's better to use default values, to keep the computed property clean and to prevent the `isUndefined`check each time a value changes.

There could be more solutions to it.

Comment: A `computed` should re-compute tho.